# "zu" + Infinitiv — Warum wird "zu" trotz Modalverb verwendet?

Tags: modal-verb, infinitive

Warum wird in den folgenden zwei Sätzen trotz Modalverb "zu" verwendet?

> Sie hat darum gebeten, nach Hause gehen zu dürfen.
>
> Ihr seid früh ins Bett gegangen, um ausschlafen zu können.

Answer (score 6):

Mit Modalverben muss man kein „zu“ mit dem zweiten Verb verwenden, zB:

„Ich kann essen“ gegen „Ich versuche zu essen“

Aber Modalverben haben keine Wirkung auf ihre eigene grammatische Funktion. Deswegen überall wo man „zu“ normalerweise benutzen würde, sollte man es auch bei Modalverben benutzen.

Kurzgesagt: Modalverben entfernen das Bedürfnis, „zu“ mit folgendem Verben zu benutzen, aber man muss „zu“ immer noch für die Modalverben benutzen.